# How can I optimise and improve getting 6 possible URL parameters

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, get, url-parameters

I am in the midst of writing a simple job board and I have the URL's filtering and working how I want, everything works - I just want to know if I can improve it, if there are any security concerns, and if it is horribly inefficient.

Take the following URL section - foo.com/**in/london/at/google/do/design**

I assign each section a variable and work out the location, company, and category.

Other use cases that work:

- Switching the order - foo.com/**at/google/in/london/do/design**
- Having less parameters - foo.com/**in/london/at/google**

My code to figure out all these variables is:

```
// Get the different possible page parameters
// Only allow alphanumeric, dashes, and commas
$regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9,-]";
$a = isset($_GET["a"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["a"]) : "";
$aa = isset($_GET["aa"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["aa"]) : "";
$b = isset($_GET["b"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["b"]) : "";
$bb = isset($_GET["bb"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["bb"]) : "";
$c = isset($_GET["c"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["c"]) : "";
$cc = isset($_GET["cc"]) ? preg_replace("/".$regex."/", "", $_GET["cc"]) : "";

if ($a == "in" && $aa != null) { $searchLocation = $aa; }
if ($b == "in" && $bb != null) { $searchLocation = $bb; }
if ($c == "in" && $cc != null) { $searchLocation = $cc; }

if ($a == "at" && $aa != null) { $searchCompany = $aa; }
if ($b == "at" && $bb != null) { $searchCompany = $bb; }
if ($c == "at" && $cc != null) { $searchCompany = $cc; }

if ($a == "do" && $aa != null) { $searchCategory = $aa; }
if ($b == "do" && $bb != null) { $searchCategory = $bb; }
if ($c == "do" && $cc != null) { $searchCategory = $cc; }

if ($a == "missinghtml") { $errorUrl = true; }
```

I'm looking at this thinking there must be a better to do this, and is this section secure?

Any thoughts on this are much appreciated. Like I say it works, but can it be better? Thanks :)

Comment: If the result for each of these paths is always of the same type: say a list of search hits of the same type, then it would be fine to simply use a query string - unless you really need caching and bookmarking etc. which is probably a bit easier with only url path variables. For code review, you can also post at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the Code Review forum, cross posted there now, thanks :)

Comment: @Craig, if you've posted this on Code Review, please delete your Stack Overflow question